# iOS: Code Coverage Confusion

Tags: unit-testing, ios7, code-coverage, xctest

Gone through the 
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/xcode-coverage/

link. Being new to unit testing I would like to know how the code coverage identifies the source code being covered ?
My theoretical question:
In a model class [subclass of NSObject] containing three methods M1, M2, M3 we do create an XCTestCase subclass with three unit test methods testM1, testM2, testM3. If we are able to run all these three test methods and able to generate .gcda/.gcno [from code coverage] files.

My question is how from this code coverage one can say that the model has more than 80% coverage? is it necessary that if possible then we should write unit test for each and every method in model (s) and only then we can arrive to this conclusion that more then 80-90% code is covered. In short I would like to know the correlation between unit test methods and code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test methods call your methods (unit under test) with different scenarios in mind and the intention to test all (important) code paths.

To see what is being covered the app you build has instrumented program flows and the code is compiled to generate coverage files. Using this instrumentation, the program knows during the test runs which code was actually run and how many times.